# Passing value from click (this) into ajax success in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this kind of situation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click','.btn', function() {
                    var this = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ path('some-path') }}",
                        data: {'data' : 'some-data'},
                        success: function(data)
                        {   
                            var value_from_click = this;

                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

How can I pass the value from this straight into ajax success? Are there any straightforward, easy solutions?

Comment: For later reference, [**these**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) are words that can **not** be used as names for variables, functions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just rename the variable:

```
var this = $(this);
```

to

```
var this2 = $(this);
```

`this` is a language keyword and has a special meaning, use another name for the variable.

Answer (score 1):

As Emil has said, you can just assign `$(this)` to any variable with a valid identifier name:

```
var self = $(this);
```

Another option is to use `e.target` and free yourself from having to use `this` and worry about its scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.btn', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('some-path') }}",
            data: {'data' : 'some-data'},
            success: function(data) {   
                var value_from_click = $(e.target);
            }
        });
    });
});
```