# jQuery on click pass (this) into a ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have done some research and there is few similar questions out there but non solve my issue.

I am doing Ajax call on records in my report, I set / remove flags via Ajax.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.flag').click(function(){  
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active_flag')){
        // REMOVE Record
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/flag/remove',
            type: "post",
            data: { '_method' : 'delete',
                    'timeRecordID':jQuery(this).attr('data-record'), 
                    '_token':  '{!! csrf_token() !!}' 
                    },
            success: function(data){
                jQuery(this).removeClass('active_flag'); // (this) doesn't refer to same (this) inside the click function
            }
        });
    }
```

I have also tried solution form this link [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919986/passing-value-from-click-this-into-ajax-success-in-jquery), but that didn't solve my problem.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.bind` to get your `this` in order.

```
success: function(data){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('active_flag');
}.bind(this)
```

After that read up on what `.bind` does [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: This works! Thanks will accept in 10 when timer is up

Comment: Please explain what the problem was

Answer (score 5):

define `$(this)` at first

```
jQuery('.flag').click(function(){  
        var ThisIt = $(this); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        if(ThisIt.hasClass('active_flag')){

            // REMOVE Record
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/flag/remove',
                type: "post",
                data: { '_method' : 'delete',
                        'timeRecordID': ThisIt.attr('data-record'), 
                        '_token':  '{!! csrf_token() !!}' 
                        },
                success: function(data){
                    ThisIt.removeClass('active_flag'); // (this) doesn't refer to same (this) inside the click function
                }
            });

        }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this it didn't work I will try one more time.. it kept telling me that thisIt.removeClass() is not a fucntion

Comment: @IamCavic make sure the `this` your referencing is a jQuery object reference of `this`, like Mohamed did in his example (not doing this is a common mistake).

Comment: Thanks for help I did try this exactly like you showed it here but it didn't work. I have possibly typed something wrong (but I don't think I did). thanks for help, however I will accept answer below with the .(bind) it worked

Comment: @IamCavic this should work. What do you get when you do `console.log(this, ThisIt);`?

Comment: This is not the way to do it properly though... Creating a new variable when you can just rebind using `.bind` instead and get rid of this hassle.

Comment: When I did like that it showed `success` in the log

Comment: @limelights There is nothing more proper about using `.bind`, it's just a different solution. If you really want to get rid of the hassle, use fat arrow functions

Comment: @JuanMendes Which is only available in ES2015 and not applicable for this question.

Comment: @limelights Why is it not applicable? Even if you have to support older browsers, there are transpilers and that is the easiest way to make `this` become lexically scoped. `Function.bind` is also [not supported in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=function.bind)